# Comparing two lists in R

Tags: r

Hi so I have two nearly identical data sets, however one has some values the other doesn't and I'm trying to compare them in R. I'm trying to create a list of the observations in the two data sets that aren't shared between the two, but I'm struggling with how to do this. I'm relatively new to R.

Comment: Check out the [{waldo}](https://waldo.r-lib.org/) package. This is exactly what it was built to do

Answer (score 1):

You should try the `arsenal` package.

try

```
install.packages("arsenal")
library(arsenal)

captureVariable <- summary(arsenal::comparedf(list1,list2))

captureVariable[["diffs.byvar.table"]]
```

There are some other helpful outputs that will be captured by `captureVariable` if that particular table  doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Did this help you at all?